# create a copy of all tables with its key and other constraints from sql-server database to another database

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, database, sqlalchemy

I try to copy the sql-server's table with its keys and other constraints through SQLAlchemy in python

```
`from sqlalchemy import *
DATABASE_CONN = f'mssql://@{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?driver={DRIVER}'
```

`DATABASE_CONN2 = f'mssql://@{SERVER}/{DB2}?driver={DRIVER}'`

```
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONN)
```

`engine2 = create_engine(DATABASE_CONN2)`

`connection = engine.connect() connection2 = engine2.connect()`

`metadata = MetaData() table = Table('table_name', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine) table.create(engine2)`

ERROR:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: table_name
```

if i putting the specific table name instead of 'table_name' then it create that table in new databse but i have to do it for all table so any technique to resolve this issue and make the copy of all table with its keys and other constraint at one go.

Comment: Please don't post your question title in all capital letters. It's considered shouting.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question and fix the formatting so that it is all one block of code.

Comment: You could load `select name from sys.tables` into a pandas Data Frame and loop over that, assigning each table name to a variable and using that in place of `table_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You recreate all the table schema from one database in a second by reflecting the first into a metadata object and then creating the tables in the second:

```py
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(engine)
meta.create_all(engine2)
```

It's possible to control precisely which tables get reflected - review the docs for [Reflecting Database Objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects) and [metadata.reflect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect).